# redirecting rule in htaccess to specific page when that page or directory isnt available

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want to create htaccess rewrite rule so that when any file or folder isn't not there physically it should keep url in same browser but display example.php so that I can check the url entered and compare it with those stored in database and show appropriate page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond   %{REQUEST_FILENAME}   !-d
RewriteCond   %{REQUEST_FILENAME}   !-f
RewriteRule   ^(.*)$   example.php?url=$1 [L]
```

If requested url does not match any directory/file, it will call example.php (you can get url with $_GET['url'] in your example.php file).

Do your business logic there to find an appropriate page for user but don't forget to send a 404.

Also, put your other rules above this one, otherwise everything is going to be redirected to example.php

**Or you could do it differently (more appropriate and easier):**

```
ErrorDocument 404 /example.php
```

And you get back the requested url in example.php with

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
```

Answer (score 0):

What I think you want is just a normal 404 page.

```
ErrorDocument 404 /example.php
```

In the page "example .php" you need to get the the page request.

Add the function

```
<?php
function curPageURL() {
 $pageURL = 'http';
 if ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") {$pageURL .= "s";}
 $pageURL .= "://";
 if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80") {
  $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
 } else {
  $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
 }
 return $pageURL;
}
?>
```

And then call it using

```
<?php
  $page = curPageURL();
?>
```

Now in $page you have the broken address the user has tried to reach and you can do whatever you want with it, for example, trying to compare it with those stored in database and show appropriate page. Personally i would store also the IP of the person just to check if the user was doing anything weird, like messing with my website.

[How to Get the Current Page URL (source)](http://webcheatsheet.com/php/get_current_page_url.php)